# Ripes (An Integrated CPU Design Teaching Tool)

Tags: branch-prediction

## **below is the question**

In the version of Ripes with branch prediction, select the 32-bit 5-stage processor with branch
prediction and load the provided program matrixmul.asm Download matrixmul.asm. This is a
precompiled version of the matrixmul.c example, with matrix order 8. You can review that code if
it helps you answer this question.
Run the program with each of the 5 predictor presets, which preset gives the best accuracy and
why? Make sure that you reset the predictor state before each run.
Score: 2.75 out of 6

## **problem i am facing**

**i am using RIPES v2.2.5-10**
[selecting processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb6go.jpg)

when i select process there is no option to choose the predictor presets, how can i get these 5 predictor presets.?
i Just need to solve this question, if someone know another way, let me know how can i do that , it would be very helpful

i need to know how can i use the 32-bit 5-stage processor with branch
prediction